# Debain package won't build as it's claiming it can't find any of the modules

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packaging

I'm building an application with "Quickly" a tool provided by Ubuntu, however the generated app won't build. I get this output while running "quickly package --verbose":

```
ERROR: Python module one_click_installer_lib not found
ERROR: Python module PleasewaitdialogDialog not found
ERROR: Python module one_click_installerconfig not found
ERROR: Python module Builder not found
ERROR: Python module one_click_installer_lib.helpers not found
ERROR: Python module one_click_installer not found
ERROR: Python module one_click_installer_lib not found
ERROR: Python module helpers not found
ERROR: Python module preferences not found
ERROR: Python module one_click_installer not found
ERROR: Python module one_click_installer not found
ERROR: Python module helpers not found
ERROR: Python module preferences not found
ERROR: Python module Window not found
ERROR: Python module one_click_installerconfig not found
```

I'm not sure what i've done to cause the error. Here is the setup.py i have used: http://tinypaste.com/c4bae9

Thanks in advance,

Joe

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/157984/python-module-helpers-not-found-error-when-using-quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ignored it and checking the source, seems to have worked.... strange :G